# Angular 2 is removing JSON curly braces on HTTP POST response

Tags: json, angular

Hello I have an issue where I am making a POST request to an API in Angular 2 and when I make the HTTP call, the Angular 2 returns a response, but instead of the expected JSON response, it returns a response in plain text with all the curly braces removed.

Example:

```
instead of {"type" : "string"} I get "typestring".
```

Here is my code:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.post('api url', body, options).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

I understand there is a data.json() function but when I try that it just gives a

```
Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 error.
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: please remove `angularjs` from the tag if this is specific to `angular` (angular 2)

Comment: also, what do you get in your network?

Comment: try hitting the server with postman or some other tool and see the response,Seems like backend problem

Comment: When I look at the network tab the request seems to be going through fine. I get a 200 response code, and the network timing diagram shows some green bars with the bluewaterfall color following it. Sorry I am not well versed with the network feature on chrome..

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya I did that already, and it works fine in postman.

Comment: in the network tab ,you will have the json response as well.Please click on it to see the response and update your question with that response

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya so I looked at the response tab, and it still not in JSON. I should note when I look at headers, the response option has been set to plain/text for some reason and I am sure I didnt do that myself. I dont think the backend did as well as it defaults to JSON in postman. Also I set the request type to applicaiton/json.

Comment: please take a screenshot of your the response in postman and chrome and update  the question .

Answer (score 0):

try this 
**service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    createRecored(body: any): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });      
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        this.http.post('api url', body, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
    }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService ) {}
    doPost() {
        this.myService.createRecored(body)
            .subscribe(data => {
                  console.log('data', data);
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried this however and I keep getting the Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 error. When I look in chrome the response type is defaulting to plain text in non json format. I do this nowhere in my code. Is there any way I could change it?